# How to authenticate with Routes in React.js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes, react-router, jsx

I use this method to show private pages to the user. The problem is that no page is displayed to me, but the logs that I put in `PrivatePage` work properly.

`Components` are **correct because when I simply call the routes, the components are returned correctly** but it has a problem with `PrivatePage` and does nothing.

**Error Text:**

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
> Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
> array instead.

I must verify that user through the server before the user goes to an address because the user has a time limit to use the site, so I used `Promise`.

```
function Auth() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let appData = GetAppData();
        if (appData.UserToken.length == 0) {
            reject(-2);
        }

    let request = {
        Token: appData.UserToken,
        UserId: appData.UserId
    }

    axios.post("****UserValidUrl****", request).then(response => {
        switch (response.data.Type) {
            case 10:
                resolve(10);
                break;
            case -2:
                reject(-2);
                break;
            case -13:
                reject(-13);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        reject(-13);
    })
})
}
```

**PrivatePage:**

```
const PrivatePage = ({children, ...rest}) => (
     return <Route
    {...rest}
    render={async ({location }) => {
        let type = 10;
        try {
            type = await Auth();
        } catch(e) {
            type = -13;
        }

        Log(type);

        switch (type) {
            case 10:
                return children;
                break
            case -2:
                return (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: '/Auth/Login',
                            state: { from: location },
                        }}
                    />)

            case -13:
                return (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: '/NotFound',
                            state: { from: location },
                        }}
                    />)
                break;
        }}
    }/>
)
```

**BasePage:**

```
export default function BasePage() {
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={"/Auth/Login"} component={Login}/>
                    <PrivatePage path={"/"}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home}/>
                            <Route exact path={"/Dashboard/Home"} component={Home}/>
                            <Route exact path={"/Dashboard/Profile"} component={Profile}/>
                            <Route component={NotFound}/>
                        </Switch>
                    }/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...props}) {
    let [PAGE_LOADING, SET_PAGE_LOADING] = useState(LOADING_TYPE.Loading);
    let [AUTHENTICATION, SET_AUTHENTICATE] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        Auth().then((resolve) => {
            SET_AUTHENTICATE(resolve);
        }).catch((reject) => SET_AUTHENTICATE(reject))
            .then(() => SET_PAGE_LOADING(LOADING_TYPE.Default))
    }, [])

    return (
        PAGE_LOADING === LOADING_TYPE.Loading && AUTHENTICATION == 0 ?
            <CtLabel/> :
            <Route
                {...props}
                render={props => (
                    AUTHENTICATION == 10 ?
                        <Component {...props}/> :
                        <Redirect to={ROUTE_PATH.LOGIN}/>
                )}/>
    )
}
```

**And for Used:**

```
export default function BasePage() {

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                {/*Other Routes*/}
                <Private path={***} component={Home} exact/>
                <Private path={***} component={Profile} exact/>
                {/*Other Routes*/}
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this in your private route.

**PrivatePage**

```js
const PrivatePage = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={async ({ location }) => {
      let isAuthenticated = false;
      try {
        isAuthenticated = await Auth();
      } catch(e) {
        // If you want to log the error.
      }
    
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        return children;
      }
      return (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: location },
          }}
        />
      );
    }}
  />
);
```

**BasePage**

```js
export default function BasePage() {
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={"/Auth/Login"} component={Login}/>
                    <PrivatePage path={"/"}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home}/>
                            <Route exact path={"/Dashboard/Home"} component={Home}/>
                            <Route exact path={"/Dashboard/Profile"} component={Profile}/>
                            <Route component={NotFound}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </PrivatePage>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**EDIT**

**PrivatePage** for specific numeric value in Auth.

```js
const PrivatePage = ({children, ...rest}) => (
     return <Route
    {...rest}
    render={async ({location }) => {
        let authenticated = false;
        try {
            authenticated = await Auth();
        } catch(e) {
            // If you want to log the error.
        }

        if(authenticated === -2) {
          // redirect one
        } else if (authenticated === -13) {
          // redirect two
        } if (authenticated) {
            return children;
        }

        return (
            <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: "/Auth/Login",
                    state: { from: location },
                }}
            />
        );
    }}
/>
)
```

Comment: The location is added to state just in case if you have any query params in the current route and want to carry forward the same.

Comment: not working , The error that gives : **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Comment: Are you passing the list of `Routes` without `Switch` or any container? The `PrivatePage` expects single children.

Comment: I have several **PrivatePages**, I have updated the post again, can you fix the problem?

Comment: Can you please use the components I have created and update the example? I have updated the BasePage and PrivatePage components.

Comment: I post Updated!

Comment: Buddy you also need to update the PrivatePage component accordingly. You are using the `await` as well as `then`.

Comment: i updated post, But the value of Auth() is a numeric value that if -2 or -13 returns, with these I want to go to a page that I want later.

Comment: Added `PrivatePage` component with special handling.

Comment: i updated post, but Again, is this solution correct?

Comment: You have multiple codes. I don't understand why there are multiple codes. Plus you may need to render the children in `case 10`.

Comment: My bad. Can you please take the async/await out in the component. In render it may not work. I'll update the example soon.

Comment: I must verify that user through the server before the user goes to an address because the user has a time limit to use the site, so I used **Promise**

Comment: i updated post, and text

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation looks complex for authentication. you can treat your component as route and do routing as this.

Assuming that you have authenticated separately and you just check if it's good to go, instead of trying to authenticate every single time for route. If you prefer this authentication on route, still solution applies.

```
function AuthenticatedRoute({ children, ...props }) {
  const isAuthenticated = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <Route {...props}>{children}</Route>
  ) : (
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: location },
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

and use it like:

```
<AuthenticatedRoute path="/Dashboard/Home" exact>
  <h1>Hey Doctor Strange! You made it</h1>
</AuthenticatedRoute>
```

I also have created a protected auth routing in this code sandbox for reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-poincare-l2c06?file=/src/App.js:262-488

Comment: It is not complicated. I authenticate the user before any page that wants to run because the user has a time limit to work with the site, so his time should be checked on each page. If there is an incomprehensible part of the code, send a message to explain it.